# Display Array that included on Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need some help.

I have an array structure like this.

```
$data = array(
        'id_packet' => NULL,
        'name_packet' => NULL,
        'number_of_users' => NULL,
        'number_of_blogs' => NULL,
        'number_of_accounts' => NULL,
        'price' => NULL,
        'period' => NULL,
        'status' => 1,
);
```

Where `'number_of_users' => NULL, 'number_of_blogs' => NULL, 'number_of_accounts' => NULL,` are the results of the following search in a database:

```
$n=1;
foreach ($list_component as $dt) { 
        $comp[$n] = $dt->name_comp;
        echo "'".$comp[$n]."' => NULL,";
        $n++;
}
```

and it has successfully displayed the expected results.

I want to ask, how to include  `'number_of_users' => NULL, 'number_of_blogs' => NULL, 'number_of_accounts' => NULL,` in the $data array above?

I've been looking for some reference, but have not managed to find any.
Perhaps one of you can help or have any idea?
Thanks.

Framework: Phalcon

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$data = array(
        'id_packet' => NULL,
        'price' => NULL,
        'period' => NULL,
        'status' => 1,
);
$n=1;
foreach ($list_component as $dt) { 
        $comp[$n] = $dt->name_comp;
        $data[$comp[$n]]= NULL;
        $n++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if (empty($value)){
        $disp = 'NULL';
    } else {
        $disp = $value;
    }
    echo "'".$key."' = ".$disp.",\n";
}
```